# `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA` is deprecated, what column should I use as an alternative

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to load all the pictures from the media provider to my app by using `MediaStore` API, but this column `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA` is deprecated. So, what can I use as an alternative?

I want to update the following code to get rid of the deprecated `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA` column:

```kotlin
fun ContentResolver.loadImagesPaths(): List<String> {
    val uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    val images = mutableListOf<String>()
    val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)
    query(uri, projection, null, null, null)?.use { cursor ->
        val dataColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            images += cursor.getString(dataColumn)
        }
    }
    return images
}
```

Edit:

Updated code:

```kotlin
fun ContentResolver.loadImagesUris(): List<Uri> {
    val uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    val images = mutableListOf<Uri>()
    val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
    query(uri, projection, null, null, null)?.use { cursor ->
        val idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            images += ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, cursor.getLong(idColumn))
        }
    }
    return images
}
```

Check out this link for further details on how to access media files from shared storage: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media

Comment: See: https://developer.android.google.cn/training/data-storage/shared/media?hl=en#query-collection

Answer (score 28):

I was able to replace MediaStore.MediaColumns.Data with its own file ID (incredibly, files have IDs) and correctly constructing its URI, like this:

```
fun getAllShownImagesPath(activity: Activity): MutableList<Uri> {
    val uriExternal: Uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    val cursor: Cursor?
    val columnIndexID: Int
    val listOfAllImages: MutableList<Uri> = mutableListOf()
    val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
    var imageId: Long
    cursor = activity.contentResolver.query(uriExternal, projection, null, null, null)
    if (cursor != null) {
        columnIndexID = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            imageId = cursor.getLong(columnIndexID)
            val uriImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(uriExternal, "" + imageId)
            listOfAllImages.add(uriImage)
        }
        cursor.close()
    }
    return listOfAllImages
}
```

**and then with Uri you build it in your Views!**

Comment: you can also use "cursor.getString()", I didn't get to test it, but it might look better than "cursor.getLont()"

Answer (score 6):

I managed to come up with the following solution, its kind of an addition to the previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57685725/mediastore-mediacolumns-data-is-deprecated-and-i-wanna-load-images-from-gallery/58203497#58203497)

but there I still couldn't load images with the obtained Uri. 
[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns) suggested to use openFileDescriptor() which I did and then decoded images' bitmaps from it:

```
override fun loadImagesFromStorage(): List<AdapterImage> {

    val uri: Uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    val cursor: Cursor?
    val columnIndexId: Int
    val listOfAllImages = mutableListOf<AdapterImage>()
    val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
    cursor = context.contentResolver
        .query( uri, projection, null, null, null)

    if ( cursor != null ){
        columnIndexId = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){

            val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, cursor.getLong(columnIndexId))

            //here I open FileDescriptor and then decode it into Bitmap
            var image: Bitmap
            context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(contentUri, "r").use { pfd ->
                if( pfd != null ){
                    image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(pfd.fileDescriptor)
                    listOfAllImages.add(AdapterImage(image))
                }
            }

        }
        cursor.close()
    }

    return listOfAllImages
}
```

P.S. My method will return a list of AdapterImage objects that I use later in app but you can put anything you need there at this point

Comment: Previously, I was loading all images with `Glide` using the file paths. How can I use Glide with `openFileDescriptor`? Like you, I was unable to get things working only with the `Uri`.

Comment: @user246392 I am late to answer but you can simply use the generated contentUri as  in the answer above with Glide.
val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, cursor.getLong(columnIndexId))

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved the problem by creating this class

```
class FileHelper {
val mediaType = "multipart/form-data".toMediaTypeOrNull()

fun getPartBodyFromUri(context: Context, uri: Uri): MultipartBody.Part {
    val realPath = getPathFromURI(context, uri)
    val fileImage = createFile(realPath)
    val requestBody = createRequestBody(fileImage)
    return createPart(fileImage, requestBody)
}

private fun createFile(realPath: String): File {
    return File(realPath)
}

private fun createRequestBody(file: File): RequestBody {
    return file.asRequestBody(mediaType)
}

private fun createPart(file: File, requestBody: RequestBody): MultipartBody.Part {
    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("imageFile", file.name, requestBody)
}

private fun getPathFromURI(context: Context, uri: Uri): String {
    var realPath = String()
    uri.path?.let { path ->

        val databaseUri: Uri
        val selection: String?
        val selectionArgs: Array<String>?
        if (path.contains("/document/image:")) { // files selected from "Documents"
            databaseUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            selection = "_id=?"
            selectionArgs = arrayOf(DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri).split(":")[1])
        } else { // files selected from all other sources, especially on Samsung devices
            databaseUri = uri
            selection = null
            selectionArgs = null
        }
        try {
            val column = "_data"
            val projection = arrayOf(column)
            val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
                databaseUri,
                projection,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null
            )
            cursor?.let {
                if (it.moveToFirst()) {
                    val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column)
                    realPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex)
                }
                cursor.close()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println(e)
        }
    }
    return realPath
}
```

}

Media.DATA it's deprecate and "MediaStore.Images.Media._ID" to get the  correct column, not working so I create column I need

```
val column = "_data"
val projection = arrayOf(column)
```

then I use getColumnIndexOrThrow() method to get correct index

```
val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column)
realPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex)
```

Comment: cursor.moveToFirst() still returns false when path.contains("/document/image:") is true.

Answer (score -1):

In Java

```
FileInputStream input = null;
    FileOutputStream output = null;
    try {
        String filePath = new File(getCacheDir(), "tmp").getAbsolutePath();
        android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = getContentResolver ().openFileDescriptor(
            sharedFileUri, "r");
        if (pfd != null) {
            FileDescriptor fd = pfd . getFileDescriptor ();
            input = new FileInputStream (fd);
            output = new FileOutputStream (filePath);
            int read;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
            while ((read = input.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                output.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            File sharedFile = new File(filePath);
            String finalPath = sharedFile.getPath();
        }
    }catch(Exception ex) {
    } finally {
        try {
            input.close();
            output.close();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Loading images from internal store.Reading all folders which has images and videos using MediaStore class.

And returning result as ArrayList.

```
private fun getAllShownImagesPath(activity: Activity): ArrayList<Albums> {

val uri: Uri
val cursor: Cursor
var cursorBucket: Cursor
val column_index_data: Int
val column_index_folder_name: Int
val listOfAllImages = ArrayList<String>()
var absolutePathOfImage: String? = null
var albumsList = ArrayList<Albums>()
var album: Albums? = null


val BUCKET_GROUP_BY = "1) GROUP BY 1,(2"
val BUCKET_ORDER_BY = "MAX(datetaken) DESC"

uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID,
        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA)

cursor = activity.contentResolver.query(uri, projection, BUCKET_GROUP_BY, null, BUCKET_ORDER_BY)

if (cursor != null) {
    column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)
    column_index_folder_name = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME)
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data)
        Log.d("title_apps", "bucket name:" + cursor.getString(column_index_data))

        val selectionArgs = arrayOf("%" + cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name) + "%")
        val selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? "
        val projectionOnlyBucket = arrayOf(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME)

        cursorBucket = activity.contentResolver.query(uri, projectionOnlyBucket, selection, selectionArgs, null)
        Log.d("title_apps", "bucket size:" + cursorBucket.count)

        if (absolutePathOfImage != "" && absolutePathOfImage != null) {
            listOfAllImages.add(absolutePathOfImage)
            albumsList.add(Albums(cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name), absolutePathOfImage, cursorBucket.count, false))
        }
    }
}
return getListOfVideoFolders(albumsList)
}
```

// This function is resposible to read all videos from all folders.

```
private fun getListOfVideoFolders(albumsList: ArrayList<Albums>): ArrayList<Albums> {
var cursor: Cursor
var cursorBucket: Cursor
var uri: Uri
val BUCKET_GROUP_BY = "1) GROUP BY 1,(2"
val BUCKET_ORDER_BY = "MAX(datetaken) DESC"
val column_index_album_name: Int
val column_index_album_video: Int

uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

val projection1 = arrayOf(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.BUCKET_ID,
        MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
        MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
        MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA)

cursor = this.contentResolver.query(uri, projection1, BUCKET_GROUP_BY, null, BUCKET_ORDER_BY)

if (cursor != null) {
    column_index_album_name = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME)
    column_index_album_video = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d("title_apps", "bucket video:" + cursor.getString(column_index_album_name))
        Log.d("title_apps", "bucket video:" + cursor.getString(column_index_album_video))
        val selectionArgs = arrayOf("%" + cursor.getString(column_index_album_name) + "%")

        val selection = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA + " like ? "
        val projectionOnlyBucket = arrayOf(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME)

        cursorBucket = this.contentResolver.query(uri, projectionOnlyBucket, selection, selectionArgs, null)
        Log.d("title_apps", "bucket size:" + cursorBucket.count)

        albumsList.add(Albums(cursor.getString(column_index_album_name), cursor.getString(column_index_album_video), cursorBucket.count, true))
    }
}
return albumsList
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use "IMediaColumns" instead of "MediaColumns".