# Android | What is MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA Replacement?

Tags: android, uri, media, android-glide, mediastore

I am using `MediaStore` to fetch the `absoluteImagePaths` and feed it to `Glide` in adapter class.
currently I am using `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA` to get the path. But, Recently google deprecated that api and may not work in near future. So, what is the replacement for this?

```
...
uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media._ID
        };

        String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER;

        cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, orderBy + " DESC");

        column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);

        
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String absoluteImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
                ImageModel ImageModel = new ImageModel();
                ImageModel.setPath(absoluteImagePath);
                arrayList.add(ImageModel);
            }
...
```

This code gives the absolute path. and then it is fed to glide through arrayList.

**Solutions Tried**

1. I tried using `MediaStore.Images.Media._ID` but it it didn't work.
2. I tried following this link [MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA is deprecated, and I want to load images from gallery to my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57685725/mediastore-mediacolumns-data-is-deprecated-and-i-want-to-load-images-from-galle) but, I couldn't find suitable replacement for my specific code.
   This link is suggesting to use the `MediaStoroe.Images.Media._ID` with some little bit tweaks. But, this tweaks gives an Uri not the absolute path. And my code needs to generate `absoluteImagePath` to feed to `Glide`.
3. I then tried to get `path` from `Uri` following this link [Get filename and path from URI from mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore) but, It led me to again `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA`.
4. I tried the google as well but, It seems I need to change the some other classes too in order to work with `MediaStore.Images.Media._ID`.

**Note :**

1. I have `ImageModel` Class to `get` and `set` `path` of the Images.
2. I have `Adapter` Class with method `onBindViewHolder` which contains `Glide` Method

```
...
Glide.with(context)
                .load("file://" + arrayList.get(position).getPath())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
                .into(holder.img);
...
```

Comment: `But, this tweaks gives an Uri` Yes. Use the uri. Remove .setPath() from your model and add .setUri(uri). Then load from uri as Saurabh showed you.

Comment: I did that. And it worked. Thanks. But, Now I tried something new and got some problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67949336/android-how-to-make-bitmap-loading-faster please visit this link .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Kotlin use this:

```
 val contentUri: Uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,id)                                     
 Glide.with(context).load(contentUri).into(holder.img);
```

Comment: Hey, I followed this, converted into java and it worked. But, I tried something new and got some problem. Do you think you can help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67949336/android-how-to-make-bitmap-loading-faster please follow this link to my question.

Answer (score 0):

As @SaurabhDhage mentioned... I adjusted the code and came to this working code. This may available everyplace but, I am posting it for future references. May be someone can get help from it.

**Inside MainActivity.java**

```
...
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                long imageId = cursor.getLong(column_index_data);
                Uri uriImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(uri, "" + imageId);
                ImageModel ImageModel = new ImageModel();
                ImageModel.setUri(uriImage);
                arrayList.add(ImageModel);
}
...
```

**The GlideMethod**

```
...
GlideApp.with(context)
                //.load("file://" + arrayList.get(position).getUri())
                .load(arrayList.get(position).getUri())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
                .into(holder.img);
...
```

**Added methods in ImageModel class**

```
...
public Uri getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(Uri uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }
...
```

This will now load the uris instead of paths.